# wpf converter "token is not valid" in editor, ColorPicker from extended WPF toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, wpf-extended-toolkit

I made a converter from string to color and back and it works fine when run but on the editor it just throws a "Token is not valid." error and prevents the editor from showing up, really annoying because it prevents me from using the visual editor.

I made the converter for the ColorPicker from extended WPF toolkit.

Here's the converter code:

```
public class MaddoColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = Colors.Black;

        if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            string c = value.ToString();
            var convertedColor = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(c);
            if (convertedColor != null)
            {
                color = (Color) convertedColor;
            }
        }

        return color;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Color color = (Color)value;
            Debug.WriteLine(color.ToString());
            return color.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And here are some relevant snippets from the form xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>        
    <wpfCatalog:MaddoColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<xctk:ColorPicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" SelectedColor="{Binding ColoreTestoRGB, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: What's the type of the ColoreTestoRGB source property and what value does it return? This needs to be a valid value that the ColorConverter actually understands such as for example "#000".

Comment: it's a string property, it looks into a dictionary for the proper value or returns a default one

    public string ColoreTestoRGB
        {
            get { return PicSettings.GetString("coloreTestoRGB"); }
            set
            {
                PicSettings.Set("coloreTestoRGB", value);
                RaisePropertyChanged("ColoreTestoRGB");
            }
        }

Comment: Obviously you cannot pass the string "ColoreTestoRGB" to the ColorConverter.ConvertFromString method in your converter without getting an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more checks to your `MaddoColorConverter`. For example, if binding fails, WPF will pass `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` to your converter. Your converter does not check for this case but instead just converts whatever is passed to string. Change your converter like this (note I've updated only `Convert` method, did not touch `ConvertBack` which might need fixes to, but that is not relevant to this question):

```
public class MaddoColorConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        Color color = Colors.Black;

        if (value != null && value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && value is string && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string) value)) {
            string c = (string) value;
            object convertedColor = null;
            try {
                convertedColor = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(c);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new FormatException($"String {c} does not represent a valid color", ex);
            }
            if (convertedColor != null) {
                color = (Color) convertedColor;
            }
        }

        return color;
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason it is expected to have invalid color values at design time - do not throw exception when at design time, like this:

```
private static readonly DependencyObject _dummy = new DependencyObject();
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    System.Windows.Media.Color color = Colors.Black;

    if (value != null && value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && value is string && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string) value)) {
        string c = (string) value;
        object convertedColor = null;
        try {
            convertedColor = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(c);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(_dummy)) {
                throw new FormatException($"String {c} does not represent a valid color", ex);
            }
        }
        if (convertedColor != null) {
            color = (Color) convertedColor;
        }
    }

    return color;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the invalid token error but now I get a an error about the string not representing a valid color, which makes sense because it's a property that looks into a dictionary, so it's a valid color only at runtime.
How would I fix that?

Comment: what is that `_dummy` supposed to be?

Comment: dummy object to check if we are in design mode or not (see how it is used)

Comment: It's just there and gives me an undefined object error, do I have to declare it somewhere?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I copy-pasted code wrong and missed declaration indeed. Fixed.